# image upload changes image lot of time after form submit

Tags: php, html, browser-cache, php-ini

im having some trouble. I have the following script for uploading a profile image, The first time the user uploads, it works fine, the second time it does no change, you select the image, submit the form, and the same image shows as profile, not the new. And i just realized that after a couple of hours, you enter to the site and the image has changed, what can this be? WHy is it that the image is not changing when submiting like in my localhost?

HERES THE CODE:

```
if (isset($_POST['parse_var'])){

if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "pic"){


// If a file is posted with the form
if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") { 
        $maxfilesize = 4109212;
    $target_dir = "users/$logOptions_id/profile.jpg";



        if($_FILES['fileField']['size'] > $maxfilesize ) { 

                    $error_msg = '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Your image was too large, please try again.</font>';
                    unlink($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']); 

        } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $_FILES['fileField']['name'] ) ) {

                    $error_msg = '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Your image was not one of the accepted formats, please try again.</font>';
                    unlink($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']); 

        } else {

      $newname = "profile.jpg";
              $place_file = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "users/12/".$newname);


        }

     } 

 }

 }
```

Thanks in advanced, I've been with this issue for 2 days now and i have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, it was that the images where being cached, so the browser was showing the cached images. The solution was to ad ? and a rand number after the .jpg at the image src.

Answer (score 0):

What are the errors? knowing the error might help to solve the problem. And check your folder permissions too. These kind of errors on live servers happen because the folders do not have enough write permissions.

Goto your cpanel or whatever you have to manage your server, check the if your users folder has write permissions.

Comment: The error im having is that the second time you want to upload an image, it should replace the old one, this is not happening